# PHP - File image not uploading?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to upload an image, it says success but it isn't moving the file into the uploads folder.

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadImage'])){
    $file = $_FILES['profileIage'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', '$fileName');
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG');

    if(!$fileError == 0){
        echo "There was an error uploading this image!";
    }elseif($fileSize > 2000){
        echo "File is too big!";
    }else{
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', 'true').".".$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = "uploads/".$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileNameNew, $fileDestination);
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

Form code:

```
<form action="my-account.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload a profile image:
<input type="file" name="profileImage"><br>
<input type="submit" name="uploadImage" value="Upload">
```

Thanks,
Ethan!

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` should be `$_FILES['profileImage']` need to fix that everywere

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadImage'])){
    $myFile = $_FILES['profileImage'];

    $fileName = $myFile['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $myFile['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $myFile['size'];
    $fileError = $myFile['error'];
    $fileType = $myFile['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', '$fileName');
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG');

    if(!$fileError == 0){
        echo "There was an error uploading this image!";
    }elseif($fileSize > 2000){
        echo "File is too big!";
    }else{
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', 'true').".".$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = "uploads/".$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

If your going to store the file data in a variable, you should use it.

See more here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Your Code would Work if you make a little Adjustments

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadImage'])){
$file = $_FILES['profileImage'];

$fileName = $_FILES['profileImage']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['profileImage']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['profileImage']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['profileImage']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', '$fileName');
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG');

if(!$fileError == 0){
    echo "There was an error uploading this image!";
} else if($fileSize > 2000){
    echo "File is too big!";
} else {
    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', 'true').".".$fileActualExt;
    $fileDestination = "uploads/".$fileNameNew;
    move_uploaded_file($fileNameNew, $fileDestination);
    echo "Success";
}
```

}

Change your `['file']` to `['profileImage']`

Comment: You may want to check that name: `<input type="file" name="profileImage">`

Comment: Thanks, was a typo